# SQLite query compare distance within rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to compare and get only stations which are within a distance range ONE TO THE OTHER. Let say I have 3 stations A-B-C they all have a position x-y-z. I would like to get the stations that are distant from 30 meters (I have a function to compute the distance so let's call it distance(x,y)).

SELECT * FROM Station WHERE ***distance(Station1, Station2)*** < 30

My problem is how can you compare distance of two different rows Station1 and Station2?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
select a.*
from station a
inner join station b
on distance(a.station_id, b.station_id) < 30;
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result is very strange... I have a lot of duplicates even if I add the condition a.ID != b.ID... how do you explain that? And can I select b in your example?

Comment: The reason for this is, that it compares every entry in station with every entry in station - a Cartesian product. The usage of `select distinct a.*` should help.

Comment: Works like a charm!!! THANKS    -   edit: Do you know how to avoid duplicate such that station.a = 1 and station.b = 2 will not show up with station.a = 2 and station.b = 1